# Flutter pushNamed in Search Delegate - Anroid Keyboard Strange behavior

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard

When I push named from the ListTile in Search Delegate, the height of the context is wrong, it seems like the keyboard is still there.

The height of the white space is equal to the height of my keyboard.
(P2)

If I dismiss the keyboard mannually, everything works fine.
(P3)

```
void showAndNavigate(BuildContext context, title, title2, gameId) {

    super.showResults(context);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteName.homeDetail, arguments: {
      'data': {
        'title': title,
        'title2': title2,
        'GameId': gameId,
      }
    });}
```

```
 ListTile(
            title: Text(suggestion),
            onTap: () {
              query = suggestion;
              close(context, null);
              showAndNavigate(
                  context, query, suggestionTitles[index], gameIds[index]);
            },
          );
```

[image: Search delegate]

[image: push without dismissing keyboard manually]

[image: push with dismissing keyboard manually]

Answer (score 0):

resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

add this to the page to be pushed